# How to initialize a byte slice in order to write 4096 bytes to os.File

Tags: go

I am trying to write 4096 bytes to os.File, but it writes all capacity - can you help me understand why the length of the slice `lenbytes` is more than 4096?

```
    // ...
    tempStdin, err := ioutil.TempFile(".", "stdin.txt")
    bytesToBuffer := make([]byte, 4096-1)
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(bytesToBuffer)
    buf.WriteByte(byte(10))
    pad(1, buf)
    lenbytes := buf.Bytes() // len(lenbytes) is 8191
    if _, err := tempStdin.Write(lenbytes); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}


func pad(siz int, buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    pu := make([]byte, 4096-siz)
    for i := 0; i < 4096-siz; i++ {
        pu[i] = 97
    }
    buf.Write(pu)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this expression `bytesToBuffer := make([]byte, 4096-1)` is initializing `bytesToBuffer` with *both* [length and capacity](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11) set to `4095`.

From the builtin [`make`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) docs:

> Slice: The size specifies the length. The capacity of the slice is
> equal to its length. A second integer argument may be provided to
> specify a different capacity; [...]

Then `buf`'s [`WriteByte`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteByte) and [`Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Write) both **append** to it.

> Write appends the contents of p to the buffer

So you end up with a slice whose total length is:

4095 (from `make`) + 1 (from
`buf.WriteByte(byte(10))` + 4095 (from `buf.Write(pu)`) = 8191.

---

Initialize `bytesToBuffer` with `make([]byte, 0, 4096-1)` instead. You can see it on this [Go Play](https://play.golang.org/p/Y_qLFm2veSn).